# Clearinterval() doesn't animate the element position

Tags: javascript

My `clearinterval()` doesn't animate the right position of the element with `-200px` value in CSS.

```js
//With native javascript
var element = document.getElementById('item');
var rightValue = -200;
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var interval;

function click(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
    rightValue += 20
    element.style.right = rightValue + "px";
  },10);
}

if(element.style.right == 0){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's not exactly the best way to clear the interval. You would have to clear it **inside** the looping interval for it to stop.

```
function click(){
  interval = setInterval(function(){
    rightValue += 2;
    element.style.right = rightValue + "px";
    if(rightValue >= 0){
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  },10);
}
```

[Here is a working example.](https://codepen.io/cavpollo/project/editor/XbVrKQ/)

**Edit:**
Although this fixes the problem you were asking for, this not may be the best approach to do what you want, as @CodeWizard points out. The button may be clicked multiple times, resulting in multiple intervals running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

First of all using `setInterval` is bad.

#### Why not to use `setInterval`?

**In some cases, the function might need longer than the interval time to finish execution**

Its a bad practice to use `setInterval` since you can call the function several times **before** the previous run has finished = **race condition**. The function will run more than once simultaneously

#### What to do instead?

Use `setTimeout` instead and call the next run **when** the current run has finished.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('item'),
    rightValue = -200,
    button = document.getElementById('button'),
    timer;

function click(){
    // Prevent multiple clicks
    clearTimeout(timer);

    rightValue += 20
    element.style.right = rightValue + "px";
    
    // Check to see if you need to call it again
    if(element.style.right !== 0){
      // Set the next run only when this one has finished
      timer = setTimeout(click, 10);
      }
    }

click();

}
```

Comment: what about requestFrameanimation for this user case?

Comment: requestFrameanimation  is for another purpose. its for optimizing the repaint of the browser. you can control when and what to paint. This event executed before the repaint is done. will not help in this case.

Comment: Timeouts calling timeouts, easily my preferred method over intervals